# CASE SQL returning Null

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

When I execute the below in TSQL I get `NULL` even though there is a value.

Here's my code:

```
CASE
    WHEN cal.Weekday = ' ' OR HOLIDAY.DateInfo > ' '
        THEN WEPHWORK.WEPHWORK + OCESAWD.OCESAWD + OCESAWE.OCESAWE 
    ELSE OCESAWD.OCESAWD + OCESAWE.OCESAWE
END as weighted
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Give us some rows to check the info

Comment: F.e. if WEPHWORK.WEPHWORK is NULL the sum will be null too.
Try to use something like ISNULL(WEPHWORK.WEPHWORK,'') + ISNULL(...

Comment: WEPHWORK 3 OCESAWD 2 OCESAWE 10.                                                                            WEPHWORK is not NULL and has a value

Answer (score 6):

Do you know your SQL truth tables?

```
( NULL = ' ' )  --> UNKNOWN
( NULL > ' ' )  --> UNKNOWN
( ( NULL = ' ' ) OR ( NULL > ' ' ) )  --->  ( UNKNOWN OR UNKNOWN )  --> UNKNOWN
( ( 'x' = ' '  ) OR ( NULL > ' ' ) )  --->  (   FALSE OR UNKNOWN )  --> UNKNOWN
( ( ' ' = ' '  ) OR ( NULL > ' ' ) )  --->  (    TRUE OR UNKNOWN )  --> TRUE
```

The last case can often catch people out.

Also do you know you SQL padding rules...?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, it is because at least one of your values is `NULL`.

In T-SQL, the basic rule is:

```
NULL + anything = NULL
```

To check why it is returning `NULL`, try the following piece of SQL. It will show you all your values laid out together so you can see why the `NULL` is being returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT WEPHWORK.WEPHWORK,
        OCESAWD.OCESAWD,
        OCESAWE.OCESAWE,
        CASE
            WHEN cal.Weekday = ' ' OR HOLIDAY.DateInfo > ' '
                1
            ELSE 2
        END as type
        CASE
            WHEN cal.Weekday = ' ' OR HOLIDAY.DateInfo > ' '
                THEN WEPHWORK.WEPHWORK + OCESAWD.OCESAWD + OCESAWE.OCESAWE
            ELSE OCESAWD.OCESAWD + OCESAWE.OCESAWE
        END as weighted
    FROM your_tables.... ) x
WHERE x.weighted IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes I have some NULL in a particular column but for other rows and not this one.

Comment: Can you screenshot the particular row for us?

Comment: Now I see why. When I add a field with 0, it treats it as a NULL. hence i get NULL back. Any quick way to convert the 0s to NOT NULL? or do I have to do it in my condition above?

Comment: difficult for people to say unless you tell them what the datatypes are

Comment: Zero's aren't normally treated as NULLs, not sure what's going on there.

Comment: The data type is numeric. Basically the field stores hours. And strange when I add field 1 with hours to field 2 without hours, I get NULL

Comment: Manage to fix it.... using..Prayer to God! and then CASe
    when  cal.Weekday = ' 'OR HOLIDAY.DateInfo>' '  then coalesce(OCESAWD.OCESAWD,0)+coalesce(WEPHWORK.WEPHWORK,0) +coalesce(SHIFT.SHIFT,0) else OCESAWE.OCESAWE  end as weighted,